# Intellij ctrl+w equivalent shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, if the editor cursor is in the middle of a word like this  `w|ord` and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, it will highlight the whole word which allows you to highlight the whole word without moving the cursor to the end or the beginning of the word then do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> arrow.

Is there an equivalent shortcut in Eclipse?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are looking for <kbd>Alt+Shift+Up</kbd> (Select Enclosing Element)

I'm using Eclipse Helios and you can change de shortcut in **Window->Preferences->General->Keys**

Comment: As with all things eclipse, the IntelliJ implementation is much smarter! I am trying to use this to select the value between quotes in an xml file and it just selects the whole tag.

Comment: And on MacOSX that is Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down

Answer (score 4):

in eclipse use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> arrow

Answer (score 3):

On Mac it is <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+down</kbd>

However, in any platform it is not nearly as clever as IntelliJ's <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>

For example, when you are inside a bracket, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>
 *excludes the brackets*, whereas Eclipse includes the brackets, so there is no easy way to select everything within a bracket. It's the same problem with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

While previous answers cover what to look for in Eclipse, this answer is to document restoring this useful shortcut set. In Eclipse Mars, for example, I found these shortcuts initially unbound.

To (re)enable, therefore, the <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+down</kbd> (using Mac shortcuts by way of example), open Eclipse preferences, find the Keys section, and look for the following:

- *Select Enclosing Element* (to bind <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+up</kbd> to)
- *Restore Last Selection* (to bind <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+down</kbd> to)